# Silverlight MVVM question

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I've completed some simple MVVM tutorials, but they were super simplified examples.
Here is my problem: I have a model class for a person, which contains some variables (firstname, lastname) and lists (education, workplaces). These lists have their own classes. For simple variables I created one viewmodel which implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface and everything works pretty well. 
However I don't know how to handle the lists. Should they have seperate viewmodels? Or how can I add these to the existing ViewModel?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to more actions on elements of those collection then you can create separate ViewModels for those classes. Then in general ViewModel you can create ObservableCollection of additional ViewModels.

Pseudo code:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<EducationViewModel> Education { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<WorkplaceViewModel> Workplaces { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to make it this way.

Comment: This works. :) I'm binding the Education Collection to my listbox's ItemSource, then binding the Name property of it to a textbox in the datatemplate. I'd like to control the textboxes isReadOnly property by binding. Where should this be implemented? I've added an editable bool property to the EducationViewModel, and I'm not sure this is the most elegant way to do this.

Comment: I'm also not sure, but I would to this in the same way - I would add bool property to the EducationViewModel and then bind it to the text box property.

Answer (score 0):

If the view present a list of things, then having a Collection as the vie model is fine in order to me. Probably you need to have the collection "Observable", by implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged` or by deriving from `ObservableCollection<>`.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, implementing the list as an `ObservableCollection` on your ViewModel will work fine. There's an [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365.aspx) to get you started; there are tons of tutorials around too.